# Controlling each UAV separately in a UCTF project

Tags: ros, rospy, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a multiple UAV launched in Gazebo world using the [UCTF](https://github.com/osrf/uctf) project which launch two groups of gold and blue colors which compete against each other in a game cube and grass pitch in the Gazebo world. The main goal is to implement path planning algorithm for autonomous collision avoidance.

After spawning both blue team and gold team e.g spawn_blue 5 10 & e.g spawn_gold 15 19 in a terminal. In attempt to understand the system I did the following a) I attempted to get control over one UAV in a team e.g iris_5 in blue team. b) Give the UAV position coordinates to follow in ros waypoint navigation c) Inspected each team control script, control_team_blue and control_team_gold to understand how to controlling team behavior.

Therefore I would like to ask for help to understand the following questions:

1. In summary how does the UCTF game concept function?
2. How can I find the publisher for each UAV for the mavros topics : mavros/state and /mavros/global_position/global e.g /iris_5/mavros/state and /iris_5/mavros/global_position/global?
3. How can I send waypoints to a UAV separately e.g iris_5?
4. Why does the state of each UAV not published to mavros e.g /iris_5/mavros/state
5. How can I find where the system publishes of each UAV of /mavros/state and /mavros/global_position/global?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255812/controlling-each-uav-separately-in-a-uctf-project/) by [DinoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29508/dinom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
In summary how does the UCTF game concept function?
```

UCTF is flying N vehicles at a time simulating as closely as possible real flight configurations. Such as running the real autopilots. This is an active subproject of the SASC project, and under active development. At the end I hope to fully document how to run it for public consumption but right now we're focused on supporting others inside the project.

```
How can I find the publisher for each UAV for the mavros topics : mavros/state and /mavros/global_position/global e.g /iris_5/mavros/state and /iris_5/mavros/global_position/global?
```

Each vehicle has it's own ROS master on which it talks. If you watch the console output of the startup you can see the masters come up on specific ports.

```
How can I send waypoints to a UAV separately e.g iris_5?
```

Contact each drone on it's own master URI. You have full contact there. Or you can use QGroundControl or other ground station. https://github.com/osrf/uctf/tree/master/doc/run_example#use-qgroundcontrol

```
Why does the state of each UAV not published to mavros e.g /iris_5/mavros/state
```

I'm not sure I understand this question. I think in general you're missing that there are multiple masters.

```
How can I find where the system publishes of each UAV of /mavros/state and /mavros/global_position/global?
```

Again see each individual master.

Also if you're just wanting to simulate multiple drones and not the full SASC setup I recommend using the --no-payload option, it will turn off a lot of integrations specific for the SASC project.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DinoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29508/dinom/) on 2017-03-01**:
To clarify on the fourth question, the control.py script of the project subscribes to /uav_namespace/mavros/state topic. However, when echoing the topic in the terminal, no data is published yet.

**Comment by [DinoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29508/dinom/) on 2017-03-01**:
For the fifth question, I thought if I know exactly where the interest topic is published(/mavros/state and /mavros/global_position/global) then I can run it thereafter then the control_team script running.

**Comment by [DinoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/29508/dinom/) on 2017-03-01**:
To also add information about my project, in summary I want to be able to control each UAV using waypoint navigation, also using the existing path planning algorithms which comes with the SASC project.